# How to change the co-ordinates of the velodyne point cloud data?

Tags: ros, velodyne-pointcloud, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description] Hi,

I have three velodynes and I launch all the three using group. I get the point cloud but all of them have the same fixed frame as 'velodyne' and when I visualize it in rviz, all the point clouds have the same origin.

I tried using tf package

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="HDL_1_base_link" args="5 0 0 0 0 0 /velodyne /HDL_1/velodyne_points 100"/> 


<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="HDL_2_base_link" args="-5 0 0 0 0 0 /velodyne /HDL_2/velodyne_points 100"/>
```

but ony the axis change but not the point clouds.

Can please tell me what I doing wrong and suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236571/how-to-change-the-co-ordinates-of-the-velodyne-point-cloud-data?/) by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Set the [frame_id parameter](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver?distro=indigo#Parameters) of the velodyne_driver to be different for each device.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0